# Different HMac Digest are being generated every time for the same input in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cryptography, sha, hmac, digest

Trying to get the digest using `HMac SHA256` with below code but every time it is giving different output.

Here key parameter is in `Base64string` format while plaintext parameter is without any encoding.

```
+(NSString *)hmacWithIndicies:(NSString *)plaintext withKey:(NSString *)key {
 NSLog(@"Input text::%@",plaintext);
 NSLog(@"Input Key::%@",key);
 NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
 NSLog(@"Key Data is::%@",keyData);
 const char *cKey = (char *)[keyData bytes];

 NSLog(@"Key Length is::%lu",strlen(cKey));
 NSData *keyInData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cKey length:sizeof(cKey)];
 NSLog(@"Key data = %@", keyInData);

//Data here
 const char *cData = [plaintext cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Input Length is::%lu",strlen(cData));

 NSData *dataData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cData length:sizeof(cData)];
 NSLog(@"Input data = %@", dataData);

 uint8_t cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

 CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

 NSData *hMacInData =[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
 NSLog(@"Hash Mac data generated is %@", hMacInData);
 NSString *b64EncStrHmac = [hMacInData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

 NSLog(@"Hash Mac generated is %@", b64EncStrHmac);

 return b64EncStrHmac;

}
```

Calling the above method as below:-

```
NSString * hMacOutput= [KeyGeneration hmacWithIndicies:@"2SagarPra2983688" withKey:@"qDwki5t1SSuKER4mzSMBHXhtt+PRMCv0B2LgXaBZmgE="];

NSLog(@"Output of HMac digest::%@",hMacOutput);
```

`hMacOutput` digest is resulting in different output every time it is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `strlen()` on non "C" strings, "C" strings are null terminated strings that do not contain any `0x00` bytes. `strlen()` counts until it finds the first `0x00` byte, on data bytes that could be early or past the end of the data, possible causing a crash.

You are trying to hard, there is no reason for "C" style arrays, just use the `bytes` member of `NSData` and `NSMutableData` along with the `length` method.
`[NSMutableData dataWithLength: ]` allocates memory.

Example:

```
+(NSString *)hmacWithIndicies:(NSString *)plaintext withKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSLog(@"Input text: %@", plaintext);
    NSLog(@"Input Key:  %@", key);

    NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:key options:0];
    NSLog(@"keyData Length: %lu, Data: %@", keyData.length, keyData);

    NSData *inData = [plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"inData Length: %lu, Data: %@", inData.length, inData);

    NSMutableData *HMACdata = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, keyData.bytes, keyData.length, inData.bytes, inData.length, (void *)HMACdata.bytes);
    NSLog(@"Hash Mac data generated: %@", HMACdata);

    NSString *b64EncStrHmac = [HMACdata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"Hash Mac generated: %@", b64EncStrHmac);

    return b64EncStrHmac;
}
```

Output:
Input text: 2SagarPra2983688
Input Key:  qDwki5t1SSuKER4mzSMBHXhtt+PRMCv0B2LgXaBZmgE=
keyData Length: 32, Data: a83c248b 9b75492b 8a111e26 cd23011d 786db7e3 d1302bf4 0762e05d a0599a01
inData Length: 16, Data: 32536167 61725072 61323938 33363838
Hash Mac data generated: b681d2b1 251f1953 3716258c 8eeb9101 db3ecad2 c4a5077e 0cf76617 e45e5459
Hash Mac generated: toHSsSUfGVM3FiWMjuuRAds+ytLEpQd+DPdmF+ReVFk=
Output of HMac digest::toHSsSUfGVM3FiWMjuuRAds+ytLEpQd+DPdmF+ReVFk=

Comment: Thanks zaph. With your solution it worked like a charm :) . Now I could see the same output everytime and thanks for pointing out the error which i was commiting.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use `strlen` for binary data. As the key of HMAC can be of any size you may be using more bytes than the key actually contains. If the key changes each time, you will get different output. You need to retrieve the size of the key from `keyData`, not from a `cKey`.